# SQL Query with multiple conditions not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, having-clause

Okay so this is my best attempt at making a query. It currently executes but returns nothing the other attempts have not worked.

The joins are wrong I believe and I'm not sure how to fix them or do this right

In this query I am trying to get the activity details with staff assigned to those activities matching all conditions below.

The staff and activities are linked in the Allocation table with a Staff ID assigned to an Activity ID there.

--**Teach at least 2 modules during 2019 in a certain campus**

The staffID must occur at least twice in the Teach table at the field StaffID

The spaID 5 or 6 would correspond to the campus so teach two modules at this time and ID.

--**Supervise more than 1 colleagues**

This is in the staff table with SupervisorID being a foreign key of StaffID in the same table.

So the Staff ID allocated to the activity needs to supervise more than one colleague with their ID appearing in SupervisorID more than once.

--**The related activity is internal one**

The activity is internal if it equals to 1.

So to sum it up the activity details should only appear in the query results if it has staff matching all the conditions above

```
SELECT Activity.AcID, Activity.Title, Activity.CaID, Activity.Internal, Activity.BuID, Budget.Amount FROM Activity


INNER JOIN Budget ON Activity.AcID = Budget.BuID
INNER JOIN Allocation ON Activity.AcID = Allocation.AcID
INNER JOIN Staff ON Allocation.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
INNER JOIN Teach ON Allocation.StaffID = Teach.StaffID

WHERE Activity.Internal=1 AND 

Allocation.StaffID IN (
SELECT Staff.SupervisorID
FROM Staff
GROUP BY StaffID
HAVING COUNT(Staff.SupervisorID=Allocation.StaffID) >1) 
 
AND Allocation.StaffID IN (
    
SELECT Teach.StaffID
FROM Teach
WHERE Teach.Year='2019' AND Teach.SpaID=5 OR 6
GROUP BY Teach.StaffID
HAVING COUNT(Allocation.StaffID=Teach.StaffID) >=2);
```

Table details are below if you want to look at them for more details

Table Activity -- `AcID, Title, CaID, BuID, Status, Started, Ended Internal`

Table Allocation -- `StaffID, AcID`

Table Budget -- `BuID, Amount, Approver, Payee, Status`

Table Campus -- `CaID, Address, GmName, Country, Status`

Table Classroom -- `RmID, Capacity, CaID, Location, Type, Status`

Table Module -- `ModuleID, Module Name, DeptID, Programme, TMode, Date_of_Firstoffer`

Table SpaceAssign -- `SpaID, RmID, TID, Manager, Approved`

Table Staff -- `StaffID, Title, FirstName, LastName, DeptID, CaID, Joined, LeftD, Current, Salary, ContractType, SupervisorID`

Table Teach -- `TID, ModuleID, StaffID, SpaID, Semester, Year`

I have tried my best to explain this well sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Please share sample input data, the expected output according to that sample, and the table structure in proper form (with column types). That makes it way easier to reproduce your problem

Comment: Sorry i think i may have it partially working and the test data i was using may be the problem so i thought I'd end the question here while I sort through and try fix it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without data It's very tough to find a solution. Please try this:

```
SELECT Activity.AcID, Activity.Title, Activity.CaID, Activity.Internal, Activity.BuID, Budget.Amount FROM Activity


INNER JOIN Budget ON Activity.AcID = Budget.BuID
INNER JOIN Allocation ON Activity.AcID = Allocation.AcID
INNER JOIN Staff ON Allocation.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
INNER JOIN Teach ON Allocation.StaffID = Teach.StaffID

WHERE Activity.Internal=1 AND 

Allocation.StaffID IN (
SELECT Staff.SupervisorID
FROM Staff
GROUP BY SupervisorID
HAVING COUNT(*) >1) 
 
AND Allocation.StaffID IN (
    
SELECT Teach.StaffID
FROM Teach
WHERE Teach.Year='2019' AND Teach.SpaID=5 OR 6
GROUP BY Teach.StaffID
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without having access to the data but you can try to change the `inner joins` to `left joins` and also:

This

```
WHERE Teach.Year='2019' AND Teach.SpaID=5 OR 6
```

Should be

```
WHERE Teach.Year='2019' AND (Teach.SpaID=5 OR Teach.SpaID=6)
```

This looks incorrect as well:

```
INNER JOIN Budget ON Activity.AcID = Budget.BuID
```

Should be:

```
INNER JOIN Budget ON Activity.BuID = Budget.BuID
```